# If $M\subset N \subset X$, $M\neq 0$, we have $\text{diam}(M)\leq \text{diam}(N)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Given the metric space $(X,d)$:
>
> If $M\subset N \subset X$, $M\neq 0$, we have $\text{diam}(M)\leq
>  \text{diam}(N)$

Negating the statement, we assume that - given the assumptions - we deduce $\text{diam}(M):=\sup\limits_{x,y\in M}d(x,y)>\sup\limits_{u,v\in N}d(x,y)=:\text{diam}(N)$. This can't be true, since $x,y\in M \implies  x,y\in N$ but $u,v\in N$ does not necessarily imply that $u,v\in M$.

I don't really know how to put it formally though.

Answer (score 1):

For any $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, if $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq B$, then $\sup{A} \leq \sup{B}$ (try to prove this yourself if you're not convinced).

If you agree with this, then since:
$$
\emptyset \neq M \subseteq N \Rightarrow \emptyset \neq \{d(x,y) \mid x,y \in M\} \subseteq \{d(x,y) \mid x,y \in N\}
$$
The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

The number $\operatorname{diam}M$ is the supremum of a set $S_M$ of numbers and the number $\operatorname{diam}N$ is the supremum of a set $S_N$ of numbers. Since $S_M\subset S_N$, $\sup S_M\leqslant\sup S_N$.

Comment: It's just too obvious... Is there a way to prove it by contradicition?

Comment: Sure. If $\operatorname{diam}M>\operatorname{diam}N$, take some number $a$ between them. Then, since $\operatorname{diam}M>a$, there are elements $m_1,m_2\in M$ such that $d(m_1,m_2)\geqslant a$. But $m_1,m_2\in N$ and therefore $d(m_,m_2)\leqslant\operatorname{diam}N<a$. Here's your contradiction.

Comment: It should be $d(m_1,m_2)\leqslant\operatorname{diam}N<a$ right?

Comment: Sure. That is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Is the OP question correct at all? consider $N:=\Bbb S^2$ and $M:=\Bbb S^1\setminus\{p\}$. Then $\rm diam(M)=2\pi >\rm diam(N)=\pi$. Isn't?

Comment: @C.F.G In that example, what is $X$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: One can consider $X:=\Bbb S^3$.

Comment: Then the diameter of both of your sets is equal to $2$.

Comment: Ah ha, diameter of $M$ as a subset of $X$ and not as a single metric subspace?

Comment: I don't understand the question. When I asked what was $X$, what I really wanted to know was which *metric* you had in mind. When you wrote $X=\Bbb S^3$, I assumed that it was the usual metric. And that's all I need to compute the diameter of $M$ and $N$. It does not matter if we see them as metric spaces or as subspaces of a larger space.